# Unable to connect from remote computer, while local connection works

Tags: sql-server, connections, remote

I have a **Windows 2008 R2 64-bit** server with **SQL server 2008 R2** installed on it.

I manage to log to SQL server with SSMS with the `sa` SQL account and with a `test` SQL account.

But when I try to connect from another computer on the same network I have the following error for both accounts:

> Cannot connect to 192.168.x.x.
> Login failed for user 'sa'. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 18456)

From the Event Viewer I have the following detailed errors

> Login failed for user 'sa'.
> Reason: Password did not match that for the login provided. [CLIENT: 192.168.x.y]
>
> Login failed for user 'test'.
> Reason: Could not find a login matching the name provided. [CLIENT: 192.168.x.y]

The error with the `sa` account implies I entered the wrong password, while I know I entered the good one.

The error with the `test` account implies the `test` account doesn't exist while it exists.

Remote connections are allowed on the SQL server.
Name pipes and TCP/IP are also enabled.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using the IP, Use yourdomain\SQLinstance

Also have you allowed the TCP port inbound through the windows firewall on the server side?

Also change server authentication:
[image]

Lastly I would change the Pass just incase

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found I used the wrong SQL Server.
So I modified `sa` password on `sqlsrv1` and tried to connect to `sqlsrv2` which explain why the password was wrong.